# read/write an NSCountedSet to plist

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing a game app where i am using an NSCountedSet as my character inventory where the inventory dynamically changes from view to view.

In other words:
the user can buy items from view 1 and add to the inventory, then the user switches to view 2 and uses some items and those should be removed from the inventory, and so on..

My questions are:

1.How can I write and read a NSCounted set efficiently to a plist?

2.is the best approach to write the data to disk as view 1 closes and the reread the data as view 2 opens? or is there a way i can read the data once when the app launches, make all the changes and then save the data back when the app is terminating?

The data consists of strings and numbers only and is small in ammount.
THe following are snippets from my code:

```
- (void) initInventory
{
//initialize the inventory with some string objects
[Inventory addObject:@"x"];
[Inventory addObject:@"y"];
[Inventory addObject:@"z"];
}
- (void) addItemToInvetory:(NSString*)ItemName
{
//add object passed in method to the inventory
[Inventory addObject:ItemName];
}

- (void) removeItemFromInventory:(NSString*)ItemName
{
//add object passed in method to the inventory
[Inventory removeObject:ItemName];
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using NSCoding rather than loading/saving a plist?

Comment: @ChrisDevereux, no i have not considered NSCoding to be honest because i thought it is a bit limited/complicated.You think it is an easier/better alternative for my question above noting that i might expand on my plist above at a later stage to include an array od dictionaries?

Comment: NSCoding is slightly more complicated (your class needs to implement a couple of extra methods in order to support it) but much more powerful and generally better suited to loading + saving state. Property lists are more limited, but benefit from being easily hand-editable which makes them a better choice for reading configurations. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/objectgraphs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001293-96936

Answer (score 0):

> 1.How can I write and read a NSCounted set efficiently to a plist? ...The data consists of strings and numbers only and is small in amount.

You can just record it using an array of (alternating) strings and numbers. The number represents the count of the string object. For a small set, you should not need to worry about the performance of the operation.

> 2.is the best approach to write the data to disk as view 1 closes and the reread the data as view 2 opens? or is there a way i can read the data once when the app launches, make all the changes and then save the data back when the app is terminating?

You can pass it (the model) from one view controller to the next, and just share the same model instance in many cases. Whether it makes sense to dispose or not depends on whether or not you need a reference, and how often that information is needed. So best practice depends on the memory and your ability to ensure the data is correct. For example, you may opt to share in order to avoid unnecessary I/O, and to keep the data synchronized, but you should avoiding holding thousands of objects if you don't need them anytime soon.

If your data were not small, you should consider something like CoreData instead (3 values is extra-tiny).

Comment: i thought i could easily record the data as a dictionary where the item is key and the number is value. but what i couldnt think of is how to load back a dictionary into a counted set. Even if it was an array, i cant think of the best approach to reload the array into a counted set as the app starts